# Is it possible to use React.js components and packages in Vue.js and vice-versa?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, react-hooks, vue-component

Let's say that I am working on a new **Vue** project and I want to use components from my older **React** projects, so copy the component files in my new project and simply import those components.

I found that it can be done using [Vuera](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuera), but I want to know if it can be done without using Vuera since it has limited to no support for newer React and Vue versions.

So, is there a way to configure my React and Vue projects?

Comment: I was looking to use react packages in my vue project but I'm not sure. I found this package while transforms the react JSX components to vue-compatible components but I haven't tested it yet:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-react

Comment: Actually, I found that this can be done using Webpack's Module Federation Plugin. This is based on the assumption that both projects use Webpack.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this one here
[Vuera](https://github.com/akxcv/vuera) it is not working currently with Vue3
but hopefully it will come soon

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: what is the affiliation here ?
it is free package on github